# Selenium: Get visible text of childs of WebElement, separated by spaces

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, list-comprehension, webdriverwait

I have a WebElement with many children (think of it as individual words).

I want to get all visible text of that element.

Accessing the text of the element using element.text gets the text, however there are no spaces between the texts of the children - all strings are concatenated and it is very hard to read.

When iterating over the (sometimes hierarchical) children like this to get the text instead, also invisible/duplicate text is retrieved:

```
texts = [c.text for c in element.find_elements_by_tag_name("span")]
```

I would like to get the visible text of the element (as in element.text) in a readable format by adding spaces between each visible text found on the site/element.
For example, it would be sufficient to add a space to each existing string in each child.

What would be a good way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

To extract the visible text of the elements you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631116/python-selenium-wait-for-several-elements-to-load/64770041#64770041) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
print([c.text for c in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, "span")))])
```